# How UIView bottom border remove?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

```
UIBezierPath *maskDefault = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskDefault moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
[maskDefault addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, 0.0)];
[maskDefault addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height * 0.8)];
[maskDefault addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 0.8, height)];
[maskDefault addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 0.2, height)];
[maskDefault addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, height * 0.8)];
[maskDefault closePath];

CAShapeLayer *maskingDefulatLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskingDefulatLayer.path = maskDefault.CGPath;

CAShapeLayer *maskingLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskingLayer.path = maskDefault.CGPath;

self.uiView.layer.mask = maskingDefulatLayer;
```

I want to remove the bottom border like the second image.

help me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this to replace your code:

```
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 0.2, height)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, height * 0.8)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, 0.0)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height * 0.8)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 0.8, height)];

    CAShapeLayer *lineShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    lineShapeLayer.path = linePath.CGPath;
    lineShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor;
    lineShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor.CGColor;
    lineShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

    [self.uiView.layer addSublayer:lineShapeLayer];

    //Bottom white line
    UIBezierPath *bottomLinePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bottomLinePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 0.2, height)];
    [bottomLinePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 0.8, height)];

    CAShapeLayer *bottomLineShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    bottomLineShapeLayer.path = bottomLinePath.CGPath;
    bottomLineShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor;
    bottomLineShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

    [self.uiView.layer addSublayer:bottomLineShapeLayer];
```

Comment: thanks. but your source code reuslt first image. i miss take my source.

Comment: Remove your code, it will be the second image left. And I update the answer to draw a bottom line with background color.